# How to save the items in textboxes for an single selected index in list box in xml and load those data? c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm relatively new to c#,I had a requirement that a set 5 text box's data should get saved for an single item in the list box.the item in list box will be added at the run time.for each item in the list box the set of 5 data should get saved.and again if we clicked an item in list box the data should get displayed.this is requirement. here i had coded which not satisfactory.so please help me that in which i can simplify the program.the way which i had conveyed may be little bit confusing please apologies for that.
**Ultimate aim : for an selected item in the list box the data should get saved in xml and if we clicked the data should load to those textbox  **

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication20
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[5];
    TextBox[] t = new TextBox[5];
    TextBox[] t1 = new TextBox[5];
    int[] tblist = new int[5];

    public struct Tblist
    {
        string text; 

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tb[0] = new TextBox();
        tb[1] = new TextBox();
        tb[2] = new TextBox();
        tb[3] = new TextBox();
        tb[4] = new TextBox();
        t[0] = new TextBox();
        t[1] = new TextBox();
        t[2] = new TextBox();
        t[3] = new TextBox();
        t[4] = new TextBox();
        t1[0] = new TextBox();
        t1[1] = new TextBox();
        t1[2] = new TextBox();
        t1[3] = new TextBox();
        t1[4] = new TextBox();

    }

 here for every new text box I need to define an new object how can i simplify this?
```

here is what when button has clicked:it save every data in the textbox for an selected index in the list box

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            tb[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            tb[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
            tb[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
            tb[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
            tb[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            t[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            t[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
            t[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
            t[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
            t[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            t1[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            t1[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
            t1[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
            t1[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
            t1[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
        }
    }
```

how can we implement a foreach statement ,so that everytime we click and save the entered the data.

```
    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
           /* textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = textBox3.Text = textBox4.Text = textBox5.Text = " ";*/
            /*TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[5];*/
             textBox1.Text = tb[0].Text;
            textBox2.Text = tb[1].Text;
            textBox3.Text = tb[2].Text;
            textBox4.Text = tb[3].Text;
            textBox5.Text = tb[4].Text;
        }

       if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
           /* textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = textBox3.Text= textBox4.Text = textBox5.Text = " ";*/
          /*TextBox[] t = new TextBox[5];*/
            textBox1.Text = t[0].Text;
            textBox2.Text = t[1].Text;
            textBox3.Text = t[2].Text;
            textBox4.Text = t[3].Text;
            textBox5.Text = t[4].Text;
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            /* textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text = textBox3.Text= textBox4.Text = textBox5.Text = " ";*/
            /*TextBox[] t = new TextBox[5];*/
            textBox1.Text = t1[0].Text;
            textBox2.Text = t1[1].Text;
            textBox3.Text = t1[2].Text;
            textBox4.Text = t1[3].Text;
            textBox5.Text = t1[4].Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, give normal names to your variables. What do these `tb`, `t`, `t1` mean?

Suppose some information about people is stored in these arrays. Then let's call them `firstnames`, `lastnames`, `nicknames`. Looks a lot better, huh?

---

> for every new text box I need to define an new object how can i simplify this?

Use loops.

```
const int size = 5; // form field


TextBox[] firstnames = new TextBox[size];
TextBox[] lastnames = new TextBox[size];
TextBox[] nicknames = new TextBox[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    firstnames[i] = new TextBox();
    lastnames[i] = new TextBox();
    nicknames[i] = new TextBox();
}
```

---

As far as I understand, you use arrays of textboxes just to store text. This is absolutely wrong.

Just create arrays of strings.

```
string[] firstnames = new string[size];
string[] lastnames = new string[size];
string[] nicknames = new string[size];
```

It is not necessary to initialize them with initial values.

---

For convenient work with text boxes that are placed on the form, place them in an array.

```
TextBox[] textBoxes; // form field


textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

Or directly set them:

```
textBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 };
```

Now you can work with this array in a loop:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxPeople.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            firstnames[i] = textBoxes[i].Text;
        }                
    }
    //...
```

Note the friendly names `listBoxPeople`, `buttonSave` (of course, give them proper names).

---

Let's save the data using serialization.

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));

using (var stream = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, firstnames);
}
```

Very simple and concise.

Data loading:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    firstnames = (string[])xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

A link to the documentation: [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8)